# Play Rtsp audio stream in Android media player

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, rtsp

I want to play an [RTSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol) audio stream in Android media player. I was trying to directly bind to an RTSP link in media player. Sometimes it's playing fine, but now it didn't play and showed a media player error:

> MediaPlayer(808): error (1, -2147483648).

Where is the problem?

Here is my some part of the code:

```
public class PlayRadio extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setDataSource(rtspUrl);
        Log.e("inside doinbackground....", path);
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                player.start();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "starting..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }
}

private void setDataSource(String path2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        player=new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            Uri a =Uri.parse("rtsp://stream.rtm.swiftserve.com/live/rtm/rtm-ch010");

            player.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),a);
            player.prepareAsync();
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Log.e("tempPath", tempPath);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, do you have the result now? I have the same problem. I use iMove to delete the video part of a video, just keep the audio, and also save as .mp4 format. I have tried many times. but it proves rtsp can't read audio stream. Also I have tried to use http instead of rtsp for the audio part.

Comment: hi Albert Chen, normally android didn't support rtsp codec to play audio. i solved rtsp audio issue by customize third party codec ('https://www.vitamio.org/en/').you can try this hope your problem will be solved.

Answer (score -1):

This error `MediaPlayer(808): error (1, -2147483648)` simply tells that your the video file you are playing is not supported by your device.

Generally RTSP links uses .sdp format which is currently not supported by Android devices.

Please check here [Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Comment: i want to play just rtsp audio stream not vedio. sometimes my program works, it can play the rtsp audio stream but most of the media player show error.i test it in emulator.

Comment: Can you upload your code in question ? may be it will solve my problem .

Comment: this link throw error rtsp://srv6.zoeweb.tv/z325-live/stream
but this link easily play rtsp://stream.rtm.swiftserve.com/live/rtm/rtm-ch010.i don't find out where is the problem.

Comment: Android Support .spd format i tested it in many devices above 4.2 and it's work fine .. so android support sdp format and in supported media format you will found RTSP (RTP, SDP)